# Norm-closed subalgebras of $B(L^p(X,\mu))$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

If $A$ is a Banach algebra that is isometrically isomorphic to a norm-closed subalgebra of $B(L^p(X,\mu))$ for some $p\in[1,\infty)$ and some measure space $(X,\mu)$, and is also isometrically isomorphic to a norm-closed subalgebra of $B(L^p(Y,\nu))$ for another measure space $(Y,\nu)$, then are the two measure spaces "equivalent" in some way?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{C} = B(L^2(\{\cdot\}) \subset B(L^2[0,1])$, so they can't be equivalent.

Comment: Even in the nontrivial case this is not true.  Consider, for instance, $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\mathbb{N}$, with the usual measures.  These are about as different as two measure spaces can get!  Then $B(L^p(Y))=B(\ell_p)$ is isomorphic to the closed subalgebra $\{QTP:T\in B(L_p)\}$ of $B(L^p(X))=B(L_p)$, where $P:L_p\to\ell_p$ is a projection and $Q:\ell_p\to L_p$ the corresponding embedding.